# Trouble Rendering Mathematical Formulas as LaTeX in my Editor in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, latex

I am currently working on a project where I need to input and store mathematical formulas using LaTeX in my editor. I have been successful in adding the formulas using LaTeX syntax, such as this:

```latex
x^2+\sum_{n\mathop{=}0}^{\infty}12+\lim_{n\to\infty}x^2
```

However, I want to view these formulas as they appear in mathematical notation, not in LaTeX format. This is how my latx equation looks

```latex
x^2+\sum_{n\mathop{=}0}^{\infty}12+\lim_{n\to\infty}x^2
```

I want to view them like this:

[image]

My current implementation is storing the LaTeX code in the editor, but when I display the formulas, they are shown as raw LaTeX text, making it difficult to read and understand. Instead, I would like to see the mathematical notation itself, as you would typically see in a math textbook or any other mathematical context.

I have tried textfeild to view it but its shows the same

Comment: Sounds like you need [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)